# Upload Teams App created using SPFx Framework to Teams AppSource

Tags: microsoft-teams, appsource

We have prepared an App in Teams which was built using SPFx framework. We are ready to upload our Custom App to Teams App Source however not quite sure if it is allowed. As when I try to upload my Zip containing SPPKG file and Teams Zip, it ends up with this error:

> Package acceptance validation error: Package Loading Failure Provided add-in package was not understood. Please, make sure that the file being submitted is a valid Office add-in package.

As I can see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/marketplace/certification-policies#bk_4

I can see this point especially:

> 1160.3 SharePoint Framework Solutions

Does it mean Microsoft started accepting SPFx Apps? If yes, How can I upload my Teams App to AppSource?

Also if it's not possible, will it be made possible in future and when?

Manifest file:

```html
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.5/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.5",
  "packageName": "<PackageName>",
  "id": "5304a64b-8c84-4bd6-8c7f-d9064ba9ee9c",
  "version": "1.1",
  "developer": {
    "name": "<SP>",
    "websiteUrl": "<Link>",
    "privacyUrl": "<Link>",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "<Link>"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "<AppName>"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "Templates for Teams to design, brand & build tabs with no coding skills!",
    "full": "Design tools for Teams to help users design, brand & build tabs with no coding skills. Copy templates from <Link> to design Gorgeous tabs."
  },
  "icons": {
    "outline": "5304a64b-8c84-4bd6-8c7f-d9064ba9ee9c_outline.png",
    "color": "5304a64b-8c84-4bd6-8c7f-d9064ba9ee9c_color.png"
  },
  "accentColor": "#36A9E1",
  "configurableTabs": [
    {
      "configurationUrl": "https://{teamSiteDomain}{teamSitePath}/_layouts/15/TeamsLogon.aspx?SPFX=true&dest={teamSitePath}/_layouts/15/teamshostedapp.aspx%3FopenPropertyPane=true%26teams%26componentId=5304a64b-8c84-4bd6-8c7f-d9064ba9ee9c%26forceLocale={locale}",
      "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
      "scopes": [
        "team"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "validDomains": [
    "spoppe-a.akamaihd.net",
    "spoprod-a.akamaihd.net",
    "resourceseng.blob.core.windows.net",
    "msft.spoppe.com",
    "d2zzvnmppezkx.cloudfront.net",
    
  ],
  "webApplicationInfo": {
    "resource": "https://{teamSiteDomain}",
    "id": "00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000"
  }
}
```

**Update 2**

Here I am trying to upload my zip:
[image]

**Option 1**: I upload a zip file having two files inside it

[image]

When I do that, I get this error:

[image]

**Option 2**: I decided to upload both files one by one.

When I first upload SPPKG file using Browse files option, it gave this error:

[image]

Then I thought maybe I should upload Teams Zip App File but it didn't get uploaded as a separate file, it actually is overwriting above file.

Comment: Can you please share you manifest file. There might be some issue with manifest packaging. Also can you try creating a manifest from [App Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/app-studio-overview) (MS Teams app that allows you to create them).

Comment: @Subhasish-MSFT added the manifest. However, I doubt its that issue as if its manifest problem, it gives different error.

Comment: @Subhasish-MSFT can you tell me if Microsoft is accepting Teams App created using SPFx?

Comment: @Nitin, do you mean a app crated using spfx component and you are trying to pull that app inside team as tab.. is it the case?
if yes, yes - you can do that. are you facing any error when you upload zip manifest file?

Comment: Ok let me update my question again with details

Comment: @Subhasish-MSFT can you see the question above updated, please.

Comment: @Subhasish-MSFT yes, its an app created using SPFx framework as explained here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/using-web-part-as-ms-teams-tab

Comment: Any update @Subhasish-MSFT?